# Front Wheel axle (Quando) with 1/4 bearings

Tags: hub, bearings, axle, front

my first post after years of using the forum.

I am a mobile mechanic and keep coming up against these Quando front hubs (sometimes unbranded) that have a standard 9mm QR axle spindle, but with larger cones (these cones fit fine in a rear hub, just not the axle) and 1/4" bearings. I cannot find replacements anywhere, does anyone know what I could search for, or what is going on here? 99% of hub servicing I do apart from OEM shimano cones etc use the "standard" but this is a wierd hybrid and it's doing my head in!!

To reiterate, I have serviced hundreds of hubs over 10 years of working so I understand the general ideas of bearing sizes. I am really looking for any specific information on this phenomenon from someone who might have come accross it before.

Thanks in advance

Dan

Comment: Could it be a knock-off ?  A counterfeit or fake ?

Comment: Quando is so low on the quality and reputation scale that u cannot imagine someone branding counterfeits as Quando. For comparison, a decent Tourney hub retails for 5 to 10€$£.

Comment: Sounds irritating. There are some fairly common BMX front hubs with 1/4" balls. I wonder if they're related.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently overhauled a Quando front axle with pitted cones. Fortunately, I do have a Quando hub with the common 3/16" and **not** the unusually **large 1/4" ball** bearings.

However, the bearings had standard sized balls at 3/16 in. I replaced them with with Shimano Y00091210 balls.

I couldn't find the exact cones as replacement. However a standard set of axle + cones did fit with only a marginal increase of distance between fork ends.

Since Quando hubs are not good at all, and usually built into low quality wheels, perhaps a complete wheel replacement would be a better offer to customers?

A 1/4" ball bearing front hub is hardly serviceable. What is more, Quando hubs need servicing very often because tolerance are awful. (My well maintained one was done for in less than 1000 km.)

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply gschenk, It is strange, unlike many other Quando wheels I have worked on, I've seen  orange/brown/bronze, and also black unbranded hubs with the same strange sizing. rear hub cones work perfectly in the hub, but the axle spindle won't fit in the fork without filing!  Anyway I have already done as you have said and explained the benefit of replacing the wheel.  I just like to offer the oppotunity to keep things going for less than the cost of a new wheel as some can't afford it. will post if i ever find a solution!

Comment: I leave my answer here, in case someone fixing a, more regular, Quando hub. I highlighted that I have the wrong hub. Good luck in finding a solution. I appreciate that you put extra effort in helping to keep the costs low for your clients.